# Adding table column with foreign key to my models in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models I have created differently for two tables in sequelize, I already defined my foreign and primary key in my local database(phpmyadmin). The problem I have now is how do I add the foreign key statement to my model.
below are my models..

I want topic_id in candidate.js to be the foreign key to topic_id in title.js.

**candidate.js**

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")
const db = require("../database/db.js")

module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    "voting_table",
    {
        vote_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true

        },
        candidate_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        candidate_party: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        vote_count: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        topic_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: 'vote_title', 
            referencesKey: 'topic_id' 
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true

    }

);
```

**title.js**

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")
const db = require("../database/db.js")


module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    "vote_title",
    {

        topic_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        v_topic: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    }

)
```

Comment: Use `belongsTo` for associations.
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#basic-concepts

Comment: I know I have to use that, but where can I place it and how.. I am new to sequelize.

Comment: Can you just help me edit this code and show me how I do it.. I have tried to understand the documentation but I can't still get it right

Comment: How are these 2 models `voting_table ` and `vote_title` related?

Comment: the topic_id in the vote_title model is the primary key and the topic_id in the voting_table  model is the foreign key.. I want to be able to do a join on both table using the foreign key and primary key

Comment: So, if i understand correctly,`voting_table` and `vote_title` are in one-to-one relationship that you want to join based on `topic_id` ?

Comment: no the voting_table has many candidates in it, which will be associated to one title in the vote_title.. Example.. imagine we are having a presidential election.  the vote_title table will contain just one tile "presidential election" now in our voting_table we will have all the candidate aspiring for the position.. so one title goes to all the all the candidates contesting for that election..